# Сравнить 2 листа гугл таблицы и выделить цветом

Tags: google-spreadsheet

на двух листах есть список товаров они заполняются выпадающим списком,
нужно чтоб на "лист 2" ячейка с товаром, который есть на "лист 1" выделилась цветом(условное форматирование).
для номеров телефонов подходит такая формула:
=ВПР($b2;ДВССЫЛ("лист1!$a3"):ДВССЫЛ("лист1!$a10000");1;ЛОЖЬ)
с названиями товаров формула упорно не хочет работать перепробовал уже кучу вариантов, ничего не работае, просьба помочь.

вот пример таблицы
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TRkdv7MZmVnd3AO2wpfvJOvoyI8yaSslDIFtbEOfelQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: без примера очень сложно что-то сказать

Comment: Зачем `ДВССЫЛ`? `СЧЕТЕСЛИ` или `ПОИСКПОЗ` с прямыми ссылками на диапазон...

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать формулы условного форматирования, например,

```
=MATCH(B1;INDIRECT("'Лист1'!A:A");)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16jJ9OG60LTZx6jlaMMSKnF_DEQ4oug883Cyn3Rw07wo/edit?usp=sharing